# Batch - Remove Range of Lines

Tags: batch-file

I have a a large text file (some 30,000 lines long) which I need to remove a range of lines from (line numbers 5-30), is this possible using batch?

Many Thanks

Comment: You might do this in "pure batch", but you should better use @foxidrive's suggestion. Batch is _very_ slow in this cases.

Comment: @Endoro That's too relative, the FOR command don't need to process all the content of the file, you can start from line 5 and stop reading at line 30 exiting from the For.

Comment: Excuse me. I understand this topic as "Remove lines 5 to 30 from a large file and return the rest". If I would wanted the 26 lines  from 5 to 30, I would used "Extract range of lines" instead. Am I wrong? Sorry, English is not my native language, so perhaps this point is an idiomatic detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the easy way you can use my routine which is easy as writting one command:

```
Call :TEXTMAN SR RANGE_A RANGE_B "Test.txt"
```

PS: I added the GetRange function for you  :)

**EDIT:** Tested with a textfile of 300.000 lines, less than one second to get the result.

> UPDATE 2

Now it accepts blank lines, unless c+ c- functions.

***TextMan.bat***

```
    @Echo OFF


:: TEXT MANIPULATOR ROUTINE v0.5
:: by Elektro H@cker


REM SYNTAX:
::
:: TEXTMAN [ACTION] [LINE(S)] [FILE] [TEXT]
::
:: * [LINE(S)] parameter is Optional for some actions
:: * [TEXT] parameter is Optional for some actions


REM ACTIONS:
::
::  AB  = ADD_BEGINNING      * Add text to the beginning of a line.
::  AE  = ADD_ENDING         * Add text to the end of a line.
::  E   = ERASE              * Delete a line.
::  I   = INSERT             * Add a empty line (Or a line with text).
::  RL  = REPLACE_LINE       * Replace a entire line.
::  RS  = REPLACE_STRING     * Replace word from line.
::  RSA = REPLACE_STRING_ALL * Replace word from all lines.
::  C+  = CHARACTER_PLUS     * Delete the first "X" characters from all lines.
::  C-  = CHARACTER_LESS     * Delete the last  "X" characters from all lines.
::  L+  = LINE_PLUS          * Cut the first "X" amount of lines.
::  L-  = LINE_LESS          * Cut the last  "X" amount of lines.
::  GL  = GET_LINE           * Delete all except "X" line.
::  GR  = GET_RANGE          * Delete all except "X" range of lines.


REM EXAMPLES:
::
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the line 3                                                       ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN E 3 "Test.txt"                                            ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                        
:: Add a string to the beginning of line 3                                 ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN AL 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                          ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                      
:: Add a string to the end of line 3.                                      ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN AR 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                          ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                       
:: Add a empty line at line 3.                                             ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN I 3 "Test.txt"                                            ::
::                                                                         ::                                                                       
:: Add a line with a word at line 3.                                       ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN I 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                           ::
::                                                                         ::    
:: Replace the line 3 with "Elektro H@cker".                               ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN RL 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"                          ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Replace the words "Elektro" to "H@cker" in line 3.                      ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN RS 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro" "H@cker"                        ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Replace the words "Elektro" to "H@cker" in all lines.                   ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN RSA "Test.txt" "Elektro" "H@cker"                         ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the first 3 characters in all lines.                             ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN C+ 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the last 3 characters in all lines.                              ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN C- 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the first 3 lines.                                               ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN L+ 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete the last 3 lines.                                                ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN L- 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete all except the line number 3.                                    ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN SL 3 "Test.txt"                                           ::
::                                                                         ::
:: Delete all except the 3 to 9 range of lines.                            ::
:: Call :TEXTMAN SR 3 9 "Test.txt"                                         ::
::                                                                         ::
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::


:TEXTMAN
(SET /A "A=0", "LINE=0", "TOTAL_LINES=0")  &  (CALL :%~1 %* || (ECHO Invalid parameter & Exit /B 1)) & (GOTO:EOF)
:AB
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE (if "%%B" EQU "" ((Echo %~4)>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %~4%%B)>> "%~3.NEW"))"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:AE
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE ((Echo %%B%~4)>> "%~3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:E
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B) >> "%~3.NEW"))"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:I
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF     "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (IF NOT "%~4" EQU "" ((Echo %~4) >> "%~3.NEW") ELSE (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW"))" & (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW"))))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RL
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE ((Echo %~4)>> "%~3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RS
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE (CALL SET "STRING=%%B" &&     (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((CALL ECHO %%STRING:%~4=%~5%%)>> "%~3.NEW")))"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RSA
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~2" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (CALL SET "STRING=%%B" && (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~2.NEW") ELSE ((CALL ECHO %%STRING:%~3=%~4%%)>>"%~2.NEW")))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~2") & (GOTO:EOF)
:C+
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set   "LINE=%%@" && (CALL ECHO %%LINE:~%~2%% >>      "%~3.NEW"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:C-
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set   "LINE=%%@" && (CALL ECHO %%LINE:~0,-%~2%% >>   "%~3.NEW"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:L+
(Call SET /A "A=%~2") && (Call TYPE "%~3" |@MORE +%%A%% > "%~3.NEW") && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:L-
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (CALL SET /A "TOTAL_LINES+=1")) & (CALL SET /A "TOTAL_LINES-=%~2-1") & (For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" & Call echo "%%LINE%%"|@FIND "%%TOTAL_LINES%%" >NUL) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3" && GOTO:EOF) || (Echo %%B >> "%~3.NEW"))
:GL
(Call SET /A "A=%~2" && Call SET /A "A-=1") && (Call TYPE "%~3" |@MORE +%%A%% > "%temp%\getline.tmp") && (For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%temp%\getline.tmp" ^| find /n /v ""') DO ((if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)> "%~3.NEW"))) && ((CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF))) 
:GR
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~4" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "(IF "%%LINE%%" GEQ "%~2" IF "%%LINE%%" LEQ "%~3" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~4.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~4.NEW"))) && (IF "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~3" Exit /B 1)" || ((CALL :RENAMER "%~4") & (GOTO:EOF)))))

:RENAMER
(REN "%~1" "%~nx1.BAK") & (MOVE /Y "%~1.BAK" "%TEMP%\" >NUL) & (REN "%~1.NEW" "%~nx1") & (GOTO:EOF)
```

**UPDATE:**

You only need to use this part of code from my routine:

```
@Echo OFF

Call :TEXTMAN 5 30 "TextFile.txt"
Pause&Exit

:TEXTMAN
(SET /A "A=0", "LINE=0", "TOTAL_LINES=0")  &  (CALL :%~1 %* || (ECHO Parametro incorrecto & Exit /B 1)) & (GOTO:EOF)
:GR
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~4" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "(IF "%%LINE%%" GEQ "%~2" IF "%%LINE%%" LEQ "%~3" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~4.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~4.NEW"))) && (IF "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~3" Exit /B 1)" || ((CALL :RENAMER "%~4") & (GOTO:EOF)))))
:RENAMER
(REN "%~1" "%~nx1.BAK") & (MOVE /Y "%~1.BAK" "%TEMP%\" >NUL) & (REN "%~1.NEW" "%~nx1") & (GOTO:EOF)
```

Or you can do it step by step:

If we want the range X to Y (5 to 10 for example) then...

1 - Write the textfile to a TempFile cutting the first 5 lines:

2 - Do a loop  in the TempFile to start writing to ANOTHER textfile the lines from the start and then stop when reached the "Y" Line.

```
    @Echo OFF

    Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    Set /A "X=5"
    Set /A "Y=10"
    Set /A "Z=%Y%-%X%"

    (Type "Test.txt" | MORE +%X%)>"TempFile.txt"

    (For /F "Usebackq Tokens=*" %%# in ("TempFile.txt") Do (
        Set /A Line+=1
        If not !Line! GTR %Z% (Echo %%#) Else (Exit)
    ))>"MyRange.txt"
```

Comment: At the very least your code does not preserve blank lines - it removes them and the counting of lines is corrupted.

Comment: thanks for giving ideas, code updated to parse blank lines :).

Comment: It has still many bugs. It removes trailing `]` it fails with `ON`, `OFF` or `/?` in a line, it fails with `"cat&dog"` in a line... You should remove the `CALL` in `Call Set /A "LINE+=1"` as it slows down the speed (and it isn't useful here).

Answer (score 1):

Batch can do it, but there will be a performance penalty and poison characters can be an issue - and the makeup of the file can be important.

Download GnuSed and run this command:

```
sed 5,30d "file.txt" >"file2.txt"
```

Comment: Only a "performance penalty" if need to read a large number of lines and if print output too, otherwise not. he only need to start reading at line 5 to 30... and the bat file can stop to read the content of the file at line 30.